# ReactJS useEffect() is running every time on page load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

My useEffect() is running every time at page load. I want it to run after I click a button. My code is as follows :

```
import React, { useState , useEffect } from 'react';


const HooksDemo = () => {

    const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(myArray) {
            console.log("My Array    : ",myArray)
        }
    } , [myArray])


       const populateArray = () => {
           var sampleData = [
               { id: 1, name: "Carl" },
               { id: 2, name: "Negan" },
               { id: 3, name: "Daryl" }
           ];

           setMyArray(sampleData);
       }


    return (
        <div>
       
            <button onClick={populateArray}> Populate Array </button>
        
        </div>
    );
};

export default HooksDemo;
```

I want to print myArray in console after I populate it using the populateArray() function but the useEffect() function is running at page load as well as after the execution of populateArray() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the normal behavior of the `useEffect` hook.
You can add your own logic determening when it should or should not call a function at page load, like by checking if the array is empty or not.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(myArray.length > 0) {
    console.log("My Array    : ",myArray)
  }
} , [myArray])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `useRef` hook, keep the original array reference in the ref container so that on every re-render the initial value is retained.

Then place a check in the `useEffect` callback so that it only runs when the array reference changes on every state change:

```js
const {useState, useEffect, useRef} = React;

const HooksDemo = () => {
  const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);
  const myArrayRef = useRef(myArray);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (myArray !== myArrayRef.current) {
      console.log("My Array    : ", myArray);
    }
  }, [myArray, myArrayRef]);

  const populateArray = () => {
    var sampleData = [
      { id: 1, name: "Carl" },
      { id: 2, name: "Negan" },
      { id: 3, name: "Daryl" }
    ];

    setMyArray(sampleData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={populateArray}> Populate Array </button>
      {}
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<HooksDemo/>, document.querySelector("#container"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</body>
```